# Sci-fi novel where genius orphans are recruited via a puzzle game and taken to a lab

Tags: story-identification, novel

I read this when I was a kid. It probably came out around 2004? That's when other books I remember from around then came out.

This eccentric billionaire ran orphanages where children could play this one puzzle game that, if beaten, it alerted him that they had a genius on their hands. He'd come recruit them to work in his lab where, among other things, they made an anti-aging serum using some exotic elements produced by a miniature particle accelerator.

Two of the kids try to escape and I'm pretty sure everything ends up exploding by the end.

Comment: Brainboy and the DeathMaster by Tor Seidler. Previously answered here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/187350/book-id-boy-plays-a-video-game-and-has-to-to-solve-different-tasks-the-last-be/187422#187422

Comment: @Frock if you answer _here_, the querant has the opportunity to accept the answer as correct — if it is — or comment on it.

Comment: @Frock I saw the title and thought "no way" but upon Googling it I instantly recognized that cover. Leave an answer and I'll accept it. For what it's worth, your link doesn't work on mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### [Brainboy and the DeathMaster](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2645918-brainboy-and-the-deathmaster) by Tor Seidler

> Darryl Kirby is an orphan. He is also a whiz at computer games -- especially those conceived by Keith Masterly, the greatest software guru of all time. But when Darryl plays a new prototype of his favorite game, StarMaster, strange things begin to happen. After he finds his way through a tortuous maze and answers questions that could stump a scientist, a mysterious message -- "WANT TO PLAY?" -- invites him into a game in which the stakes are higher than they first appear -- a game that eventually lands him in a luxurious laboratory where Masterly has enlisted a brain trust of children for a secret purpose of his own. Befriended by Nina, who suspects Masterly's motives, Darryl slowly uncovers a sinister plan and finds himself the star in his own real-life computer game. But will he and Nina be able to stop Masterly and escape before it is too late?
>
> Brainboy and the Deathmaster is a fast-paced, high-tech mystery-adventure by National Book Award finalist Tor Seidler, author of the modern-day classic Mean Margaret.

[image: Brainboy and the DeathMaster front cover]

---

Credit to @Frock for finding this story and is answered in more detail [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/187350/58193).